# Get a string value from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, authentication

I am developing a login system using in asp.net and using a SQL Server database. I did not add yet the security part, this is just a login for testing, so this is not my concern for the moment.

I have an `Account` table in the database with columns `username`, `password` and `acc_type`. What I want during the login is if the credentials are correct, the account type needs to be checked then, and depending on the type of the account, the user will be redirected to its corresponding page.

Here is my code so far:

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=AA-PC\\SQLSERVER2012;Initial     Catalog=oncf;Integrated Security=True";

    con.Open();

    string query = "SELECT count(*) FROM Account where acc_username=@username and acc_password=@password";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox1.Text); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox2.Text);

    int count= Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

    if(count==1) 
    {
        string query2 = " SELECT acc_type FROM Account where acc_username=@username and acc_password=@password";

        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, con);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox2.Text);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
        da.Fill(dt);

        string userType = dt.Rows[0]["acc_type"].ToString();

        if (userType == "LandAsset")
        {
            Response.Redirect("ManageLines.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("MainAdmin.aspx");
        }
    }
    else {
        Label2.Visible = true;
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

I have an outer if else condition to check if the credentials are correct, if it is the case, then we have the logic checking which type of account it is.

However, whenever I try to login, no matter what type the user is, I am always redirected to the same `MainAdmin.aspx` page..

Can anyone help with that please?

Comment: Do not store passwords in a database, salt and hash them instead.

Comment: Yeah I have a function ready for that, but I am not including it in here. This is just a login part for testing.

Comment: Usually these problems are really easy to fix if you start to use the debugger

Comment: Did you Debug and see what string UserType is actually receiving when it gets past that line? It seems to me that you are never getting LandAsset back.... so thats why you are getting redirected.

Comment: How can I do that? I think that code is fine, there is nothing that looks wrong, it should normally get LandAsset

Comment: I just checked the variable content, and it is exactly LandAsset, but I am still getting redirected to the same page! This is driving me crazy !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing this way too complicated!

Basically, if your user and his password are in fact present in the table, your second query will return his `account_type` - and vice-versa, if that user doesn't exist, or if the password is wrong, then no value (or `NULL`) will be returned - just check that. Also: since you're returning **exactly one row, one column**, you can use the much simpler `.ExecuteScalar()` instead of filling a `DataTable` and then scouring around in it to find the information you need ..

So basically, this code should do the same:

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // set up your connection string and query as strings
    string connectionString = "Data Source=AA-PC\\SQLSERVER2012;Initial Catalog=oncf;Integrated Security=True";
    string query = "SELECT acc_type FROM dbo.Account WHERE acc_username = @username and acc_password = @password;"

    // set up your connection and command in "using" blocks
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        // define and set parameters
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = TextBox1.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = TextBox2.Text);

        // open connection, execute command, close connection
        con.Open();

        object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        con.Close();

        // if nothing was returned -> user/password are not valid
        if (result == null) {
            Label2.Visible = true;
        }
        else  
        {
            string accountType = result.ToString();

            if (accountType == "LandAsset")
            {
                 Response.Redirect("ManageLines.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                 Response.Redirect("MainAdmin.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I will change the datatable and use executeScalar. But why did you use only one command in this code? You also used both cmd and cmd2.

Comment: @simon: I **only** use `cmd2` (was easier to just use what you had) - my code uses **only one query** to achieve what you're trying to do

Comment: But what is the most used way to do a login like this?
The problem I am having is that I always get redirected to the same page whatever type the user is

Comment: @simon: then you need to **debug your code** and see what value you get back from the database table, and how it's being used in your code .... there could e.g. be a trailing space in the value you get back from the database (so it would be "LandAsset "). What **datatype** is that column in your table?? If it's a `CHAR(20)` or something like that, it would be **padded with spaces** to the **defined length** (of 20 characters in my example here) - something must be **wrong** somewhere - but that has nothing to do with this query here!

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! The problem was indeed the column size in the database. "LandAsset" contains 9 characters while I had put a size of 10 for that column, so even though the string gotte from the DB was LandAsset, it wasnt the same as the one I wasnt comparing it to.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, if security is an issue, I don't recommend you do this.

The major flaw I see with this system is that all your authenticated users can easily share links between themselves or simply type `ManageLines.aspx` in their browsers and access unauthorized areas of your application.

To answer your second question "But what is the most used way to do a login like this?", may I recommend asp.net role management?

I've used it successfully and it works beautifully. As in many areas of ASP, most of the work is already done for you.

This link will give you a general overview:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ab2fxh0(v=vs.100).aspx

Use the aspnet_regsql.exe utility to configure all the necessary tables and stored procedures in your SQL server:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(v=vs.140).aspx

Then in SQL, create a record in the app table, roles for that app, add members to the roles. This is all done in SQL with stored procedures provided by regsql.

Next, modify your web.config to include a role provider. You can then add your users to a role using the stored procedures.

```
<roleManager 
     defaultProvider="SQL"
     enabled="true" 
     cacheRolesInCookie="true" >
</roleManager>
```

In your `web.config`, instead of `<allow users="bob">` you will have

```
<authorization>
    <allow roles="LANDASSET" />
    <allow roles="ADMIN" />
    <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

You can then create subfolders called "LANDASSET" and another called "ADMIN" stick the appropriate files in there, and in `web.config` add:

```
<location path="LANDASSET">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="LANDASSET" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>

<location path="ADMIN">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="ADMIN" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Note the ROLES and APPLICATION name spelling and case must all match between SQL and your web.config or they will not connect, even if your connection string and role provider are accurate.

Finally, if you still want to give your users the convenience of redirecting them on login, you can add this to your login codebehind:

make sure you have this at the top:

```
using System.Web.Security;
```

then in your method, add:

```
    string username = TextBox1.Text;

        if (Roles.GetRolesForUser(username) == "LANDASSET")
        {
             Response.Redirect("ManageLines.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
             Response.Redirect("MainAdmin.aspx");
        }
```

It may take some additional reading to accomplish, but these are the basics.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help!